# My code does not convert string row.cells but convert string value

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, webforms

I have code that converts a string from "ISO-8859-1" to "windows-1256" charset. For example, when I set `p_word = "ÓíÏÉ Úáí ÇáØíÈ` it converts it succesfully.
But when I set `p_word = row.Cells[1].Text` When I display it in the label, it equals `ÓíÏÉ Úáí ÇáØíÈ` it's does not work, any one can help?
this my code:

```
protected string convert_to_readable(string p_word)
{
    string unreadable = p_word;
    Encoding Unkown_lang = Encoding.GetEncoding("ISO-8859-1");
    Encoding Arabic_lang = Encoding.GetEncoding("windows-1256");
    byte[] Unkown_langBytes = Unkown_lang.GetBytes(unreadable);
    string Arabic_langWord = Arabic_lang.GetString(Unkown_langBytes);
    return Arabic_langWord;
}
```

Comment: If you've already *got* a string, chances are it's too late. There's no such thing as converting a string "from" ISO-8859-1... a string is already a sequence of UTF-16 code units. Instead, you should address where `p_word` is coming from. (I'd also strongly recommend that you start following .NET naming conventions to make it easier for everyone else to read your code.)

Comment: i pass p_word as parameter value, for example convert_to_readable("ÓíÏÉ Úáí ÇáØíÈ") just work fine, but say string x = row.Cells[1].Text; and then convert_to_readable(x) does not work,,

Comment: "does not work" doesn't tell us anything about what the input is or what the output is. It sounds like the problem is that `row.Cells[1].Text` is inappropriate to start with - but you really, really shouldn't use the code you've presented. It's a thoroughly bad idea.

Comment: the row.Cells[1].text return "ÓíÏÉ Úáí ÇáØíÈ", so it's the input, and the output is "ÓíÏÉ Úáí ÇáØíÈ", can you give another method to solve this problem?

Comment: give me another code to convert the gridview data from "iso-8859-1" to "windows-1256" please,,

Comment: I'm saying that your problems occur earlier, when you're getting the strings. An encoding conversion would have an input of a byte array (or stream) and the same as an output. It doesn't help that we don't know what you would consider to be success...

Answer (score 0):

i solved my problem by do the following:
1- add to web.config
into  `?xml version="1.0"`  encoding="windows-1256" and will be look like  `?xml version="1.0" encoding="windows-1256"?` 
2- add to my web page, into gridview data field,  `HtmlEncodeFormatString="false" HtmlEncode="false"` 
and all worked fine after that,,